# How to I change a permissions on a folder I have tried gksu nautilus with no luck ubuntu 18.04 lts

Tags: nautilus, eclipse, gksu

I am trying to change the permissions on a folder to read and write on /snap/eclipse/29 To install the jre but to get eclipse working. I have tried installing gksu nautilus over again but had no luck.

Comment: You cannot. `mount | grep snap` will show you that snaps are mounted "Read only".